# Swift syntax ambiguity in Core Data stack variables in App Delegate

Tags: iphone, swift

for this piece of code from AppDelegate :

```
lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Test102", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()
```

1) what is the syntax after the equal sign called: `var x : Type? = {statements}()` I know that the closure's syntax is `({args->returnType in statements})` or `{statements}` or `(){statements}` if the closure was the last argument in a function

2) sometimes, I see that optionals usage is ambiguous, why to use the forced unwrapping operator ( ! ) for the returned object ? why not just we use `return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)` ? and why to use the downcasting keyword `as` with ( ! ) instead of the usual operator ( ? ) in some scenarios? does `as!` mean *forced unwrapped down casting* or *implicitly unwrapped optional down casting* ?

p.s. do not tell me to read the optionals chapter in Swift or read swift books, because i've already done so.

Answer (score 1):

1) The syntax is actually a function/closure and called `Lazy Stored Property`. It works like a singleton and is initialized (once) when the property is accessed the first time.

From the documentation:

> A lazy stored property is a property whose initial value is not calculated until the first time it is used. You indicate a lazy stored property by writing the lazy modifier before its declaration.

2) If you know that the result of an expression is **never** `nil` and the result type is **always** the specified type use the forced unwrapped downcast operator `as!` otherwise use optional bindings with the `as?` operator to check both for `nil` and the type

Comment: I'm not asking about the lazy modifier, I'm asking about the syntax {statements} followed by ()

Comment: it's a normal function syntax

Comment: function syntax is func x (args) -> returnType { } or func x ( ) { } but not func x { } ( )

Answer (score 0):

After reading *The Swift Programming Language* book of Apple, the last section of the [Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203) chapter answers my question: "Setting a default property value with a closure or function", exactly reading this phrase:

> Note that the closure’s end curly brace is followed by an empty pair of parentheses. This tells Swift to execute the closure immediately. If you omit these parentheses, you are trying to assign the closure itself to the property, and not the return value of the closure